# Cross type casting operator in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, typecast-operator

I have two classes A and B, and my C++ code is as follows:

```
class A
{
int k;
public:
    //Some functions
    operator B()
    {
        B alpha;
        alpha.x=k;
        alpha.y=0;
        return alpha;
    }
};

class B
{
int x,y;
public:
    //Some functions
    operator A()
    {
        A play;
        play.k=x;
        return play;
    }
};
```

However, I am facing a problem while executing this (I have written proper main). It shows an error message: ***Expected type-specifier before B***

I thought that the problem is due to placing class A before B. However, when I channged that, i.e. put class B before A, the same type of error message appears:***Expected type-specifier before A***

How do I solve this problem (I mean please suggest changes in the code so that it works)? I need to use cross type casting in my work.

*(I have tried it with two compilers, Code::Blocks (13.12) and MinGW (w64). But same message is being shown in both cases)*

Comment: looking for the original question about this that already answers and explains it...

Comment: Never did anything like this but when your compiler is getting to the method B in class A it doesn't know what to do. Use forward declarations for your classes.

Comment: I did suggest how to make it work.  Quoting my other answer: "In general, if you use the sequence:

(\*)    Forward declare all class types
(\*)    Define all class types
(\*)    Bodies of class members

everything will be fine."

Comment: I tried forward declaration, but forward declaration itself gives a error message given below:
___Redeclaration of class B___